# Error creating bean with name 'jpaVendorAdapter' defined in class path resource

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, cloud-foundry, mssql-jdbc

Trying to deploy springboot project in cloud foundry. Getting the below error.

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactoryBuilder' defined in
>   class path resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method
>   'entityManagerFactoryBuilder' parameter 0; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'jpaVendorAdapter' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]:
>   Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter]: Factory
>   method 'jpaVendorAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Driver
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver claims to not accept
>   jdbcUrl, ${vcap.services.xxx.credentials.jdbcUrl}

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect

spring.datasource.url=${vcap.services.xxx.credentials.jdbcUrl}
spring.datasource.username=${vcap.services.xxx.credentials.username}
spring.datasource.password=${vcap.services.xxx.credentials.password}
```

build.gradle

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'

//cloud connector
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cloud-connectors'

//database
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'


implementation group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-jdbc'

implementation group: 'com.microsoft.sqlserver', name: 'mssql-jdbc'

compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-connector'
```

Expected : should be deployed and running
Actual : Error in the title

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the `'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cloud-connectors'` and `group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-connector'` dependencies from the project.

When Spring Cloud Connectors jars are on the classpath, they will create connection beans for the services detected in `VCAP_SERVICES` (e.g. a `Datasource` bean in your case). Because Connectors is creating the connection beans instead of Spring Boot, your `spring.datasource` properties are ignored. Removing Connectors from the project will allow Boot to create the connections using your properties.

Alternatively, you could choose to use [Java CFEnv](https://github.com/pivotal-cf/java-cfenv) to set the `spring.datasource` properties automatically from `VCAP_SERVICES` (once Connectors is removed from the project).